# Xcode 9, Ionic, Cordova, iOS emulator

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework

Since I installed Xcode 9 the iOS emulator doesn't work with Cordova.
When I use this command :

```
ionic cordova emulate ios --target="iPhone-6s"
```

The result is :

```
No available runtimes could be found for "iPhone 6s".
[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova emulate ios --target iPhone-6s (exit code 1)
```

And the same problem when I run emulator without target
I use the followings versions :

```
Nodejs : 6.11.3

npm : 3.10.10

ionic : 3.12.0

cordova : 7.0.1

Xcode : 9.0
```

But, before, with Xcode 8 it was Ok !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can test multiple things, to solve this problem :

1) Launch you project directly with XCode and see if it compile correctly or not, you will also see if the simulator is installed correctly, with the version of iOS you like.

2) In Ionic 3 sometimes the ios-sim node module is not installed automatically so you need to install it to be able to deploy in a simulator, launch this command from your ionic project :

```
cd platforms/ios/cordova && npm install ios-sim
```

3) Be sure you have ios-deploy installed by doing `ios-deploy -v`
If it's not installed you can do :

```
npm install -g --unsafe-perm ios-deploy
```

4) Try to launch directly with : `ionic cordova run ios` and it will take the last simulator you used in XCode

5) Last solution, delete the iOS platform and re-add it, and reinstall the node modules

Hope it helps.

Comment: I do the missing steps : 2) and 3), it's running now ! Thanks very much !!

Comment: @user7583291 nice ! validate my answer, it will maybe help other people

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't got enough "reputation" to do that.

Comment: You can't check the checkmarck ? it's not possible I think